# SQLite support in Dart command-line application?

Tags: sqlite, dart, database-connection, rdbms

I need to manage (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, etc.) a simple SQLite database through Dart code, but all the SQLite connector libraries I could find are very outdated. I've searched for a solution and haven't seen anything compatible with Dart 2. Can anyone think of an alternative way to do this?

Note: The application and database will eventually be migrated server-side
with Azure.

Note: I am fairly new to working with SQL and RDBMS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [sqlite package](https://pub.dev/packages/sqlite3) should provide what your need. It is pretty up-to-date including null-safety and recently updated.